# How to convert rectangle selection to circle(in grid)

Tags: algorithm

I apply function on small portion of rectangular 2d grid. The code looks like this -

```
for(int x = startX; x < endX; ++x)
{
 for(int y = startY; y < endY; ++y)
 {
    Function(grid[x+y*stride]); 
 } 
}
```

Now I want circle shape instead rectangular shape to apply the same function, but forgot how :S please help

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is enought for me

```
bool isInside(int circle_x, int circle_y, int rad, int x, int y)
{
    // Compare radius of circle with distance of its center from 
    // given point
    if ((x - circle_x)*(x - circle_x) +
        (y - circle_y)*(y - circle_y) <= rad*rad)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

for(int x = startX; x < endX; ++x)
{
 for(int y = startY; y < endY; ++y)
 {
   if(isInside(centerX,centerY,Radius,x,y))
   {
      Function(grid[x+y*stride]); 
   }
 }
```

}